# How to display variable name not its value in vb

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to get the variable name used in for each loop printed in vbs but unable to do so.

```
x=2, y=3, z=7
a = array (x,y,z)
for each element in a
   wscript.echo element
next
```

The above example prints the variable element value (2/3/7) rather than element name (x/y/z). how do you i get to print the element name.

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using a dictionary?

```
Dim dict : Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict.item("x") = 2
dict.item("y") = 3
dict.item("z") = 7

dim key, value
For Each key in dict.Keys
    value = dict.item(key)
    wscript.echo key & " = " & value
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=2, y=3, z=7
a = array (x,y,z)
names = array ("x","y","z")

for each element in names
   wscript.echo element
next
```

If you want to show each element with his value:

```
x=2, y=3, z=7
a = array (x,y,z)
names = array ("x","y","z")

for i=0 to 2
    wscript.echo names(i) & "=" & a(i)
next
```

Comment: thanks! if i want to use the element value in for each loop then it does not work rt. I am trying to get to display/use element name and value inside the for each loop. how do i do that

Answer (score 0):

You can't in normal programming. You are the programmer, you know the names. You put the names in the output (msgbox "Variable name is A " & A).

You can put your code into strings, process it how you want, then execute it with eval or execute (see Help).

You can do the above but use the script control (see Google).

But you know the names, and if you want to display them simply, then you type their names into the message strings.

Comment: but my array has many elements (which are already assigned some value) and each element is processed in for each loop. I want to be able to dynamically write the element name and the element value which was processed in for each loop.